Postgres permissions on table create not propagated
we are working with a postgres database V13. We're facing a problem that previously permissions were just inherited/created when a new table was created. It is not working anymore, when I create a new table no permissions are set at all.
In our database we have a user structure, where we have user groups, e.g. group1. Then we have a user belonging to that user group named user1 and it inherits from group1. Next, there is a schema that grants specific default priveleges with group1 being the grantor in that case. This schema is owned by user group schema1.
Now question Nr. 1: If I create a table as user1, shouldn't the default priveleges defined through the user group group1 automatically be applied to that table? Because user1 belongs to that group and inherits from it.
Question Nr. 2: the schema in which I create this table is owned by schema1 user group. When I set the owner of the table to schema1 does that have any implications for the table priveleges?
What I expected was a table that in the permissions has two entries:

other_user_group1 read permissions granted by user1 or group1 through the default permissions
schema1 all permissions granted by schema1

Maybe I have misunderstood how these permissions are inherited,so it would be great to further understand this. Also, if this is not how it works, how this has worked beforehand and what might have changed. Thanks so much for your help!

Ad 1: No, not at all. Default privileges are not inherited.
Ad 2: the privileges on a schema have no influence on the privileges created in that schema.
